# Select All Checkboxes By ID/Class

Tags: javascript

I'm really bad at Javascript and I'm struggling to get my head round it.

What I'm trying to do is get something to select all checkboxes. However everything I have found tries to do it by name, I want to do it by ID or class. Select all by name is just inpractical isn't it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com), you can do this very easilly!

```
$(".ClassName").attr("checked", "true");
```

or a single ID

```
$("#ID").attr("checked", "true");
```

See: [Check All Checkboxes with JQuery](http://www.iknowkungfoo.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/7/9/Check-All-Checkboxes-with-JQuery).

Answer (score 17):

```
var array = document.getElementsByTagName("input");


for(var ii = 0; ii < array.length; ii++)
{

   if(array[ii].type == "checkbox")
   {
      if(array[ii].className == YOUR_CLASS_NAME)
       {
        array[ii].checked = true;

       }


   }
}
```

by ID:

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById(YOUR_ID);

if(null != checkbox)
    checkbox.checked = true;
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Javascript

By class:

```
var clist=document.getElementsByClassName("MyClass");
for (var i = 0; i < clist.length; ++i) { clist[i].checked = "checked"; }
```

By ID:

```
var clist=document.getElementById("MyID");
for (var i = 0; i < clist.length; ++i) { clist[i].checked = "checked"; }
```

See also: [Loop Over querySelectorAll Matches](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/).

#### jQuery

By class:

```
$('.myclass:input:checkbox').each(function() { this.checked = true; });
```

By ID:

```
$('#myID:input:checkbox').each(function() { this.checked = true; });
```

Related: [How to reset all checkboxes using jQuery or pure JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2279760/55075)

Answer (score 2):

JQuery is great when there's a pattern to match. See [Check All Checkboxes with JQuery](http://www.iknowkungfoo.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/7/9/Check-All-Checkboxes-with-JQuery).

Comment: Thanks Galwegian - that's the answer that will get me on a couch with a beer before 9pm. You can't beat a working example, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code:

```
function checkAll(array_with_id_values)
{
    for (var i = 0, ilen = array_with_id_values.length; i < ilen; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById(array_with_id_values[i]).checked = true;
    }
}
```

Call it with:

```
checkAll(['my-unique-id', 'my-other-unique-id', 'my-third-unique-id']);
```

You should ofc not use such verbose variable names and do checks that the argument is an array and that the element you get is a checkbox etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

I always had a tough time with javascript.  You might want to investigate the jQuery javascript library.  It's greatly enhanced my ability to solve problems using javascript, as well as create more clear and concise code to manipulate and access the DOM.

With jQuery you should be able to easily select all the checkboxes you'd like by ID and then loop through them setting their value to be checked.

Comment: I wanted to avoid it as not everyone wants to include jQuery, but oh well. It's about time everyone used it. Its all working now :)

Comment: There's no reason to use jQuery for such a tiny task.

Comment: If Ben's having general troubles with JavaScript though, it may be a good idea for him to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

What if you give all of the checkboxes the same name + a number(ie. `chkbox1`, `chkbox2`,etc...). Then in your javascript you would create a for loop to go through the number of checkboxes you have, and do `getElementByID("chkbox" + num)` (where num is your loop variable).

Answer (score 0):

Try this using jQuery:

```
$(".className").prop("checked", true);
$("#idName").prop("checked", true);
```