# How to reset all checkboxes using jQuery or pure JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

How can I reset all checkboxes in a document using jQuery or pure JS?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

If you mean how to remove the 'checked' state from all checkboxes:

```
$('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

Comment: This script is toggling the state of check boxes. Not sure if I am doing something wrong

Comment: Note that in jQuery v1.6 and higher, you should be using .prop('checked', false) instead for greater cross-browser compatibility - see http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: I used this to reset the form before opening new dialog. After this I need to put one checkbox 'checked' and this doesn't work. When I look at generated code it is 'checked' but on my page it is not

    $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
    $('input[value='+val+']').attr('checked',true);

Comment: This is now an obsolete answer - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420534/check-uncheck-checkbox-using-jquery

Answer (score 55):

If you want to use form's reset feature, you'd better to use this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',true);
```

OR

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',false);
```

Looks like `removeAttr()` can not be reset by `form.reset()`.

Comment: Although the accepted answer works too, I find this the best way to do it. Please, if you're reading this, consider using this way, since its best practice to.

Comment: This is not RE SETTING the checkbox, is UN SETTING it, you need to use item.defaultChecked to reset to the original state!

Comment: Thanks, in my browser checking a checkbox doesn't add a `checked` attribute, it only changes the `checked` property of the DOM element to `true`, so the accepted answer doesn't work and your does.

Answer (score 18):

I have used this before:

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
```

It seems that `.attr()` and `.removeAttr()` doesn't work for some situations.

> **Note:** In jQuery v1.6 and higher, you should be using `.prop('checked', false)` instead for greater cross-browser compatibility - see https://api.jquery.com/prop

Answer (score 16):

The above answer did not work for me -

The following worked

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() 
{ 
        this.checked = false; 
});
```

This makes sure all the checkboxes are unchecked.

Answer (score 13):

In some cases the checkbox may be selected by default. If you want to restore default selection rather than set as unselected, compare the `defaultChecked` property.

```
$(':checkbox').each(function(i,item){ 
        this.checked = item.defaultChecked; 
});
```

Comment: I almost answered the same!
there is a difference between reset and unset ! UP

Answer (score 10):

#### Javascript

```
var clist = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < clist.length; ++i) { clist[i].checked = false; }
```

#### jQuery

```
$('input:checkbox').each(function() { this.checked = false; });
```

To do opposite, see: [Select All Checkboxes By ID/Class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1032827/55075)

Answer (score 4):

```
 $(":checkbox:checked").each(function () {

 this.click(); 
});
```

to unchecked  checked box, turn your logic around to do opposite

Answer (score 3):

As said in [Tatu Ulmanen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2279775/662581) using the follow script will do the job

```
$('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

But, as [Blakomen's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279760/how-to-reset-all-checkboxes-using-jquery-or-javascript#comment23137406_2279775) said, after version 1.6 it's better to use [**`jQuery.prop()`**](http://api.jquery.com/prop) instead

> Note that in jQuery v1.6 and higher, you should be using
>   .prop('checked', false) instead for greater cross-browser
>   compatibility

```
$('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
```

Be careful when using `jQuery.each()` it may cause performance issues. (also, avoid `jQuery.find()` in those case. Use each instead)

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() 
{ 
    $(this).prop('checked', false); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can be selective of what div or part of your page can have checkboxes checked and which don't. I came across the scenario where I have two forms in my page and one have prefilled values(for update) and other need to be filled fresh.

```
$('#newFormId input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked',false);
```

this will make only checkboxes in form with id newFormId as unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

I used something like that

```
$(yourSelector).find('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container check">
<button class="btn">click</button>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car<br>
</div>
<script>
$('.btn').click(function() {

$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() 
{ 
        this.checked = false; 
}); 
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. You really want to include some explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Easy. by class GIVE ME A LIKE

```
$('.YUCLASS').prop('checked', false);
```

or

```
$('.YUCLASS').removeAttr('checked');
```

Resetall checkbox

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="bike" name="vehicle" value="bike">
<label for="bike">Bike</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="car" name="vehicle" value="car">
<label for="car">Car</label>
<button id="select">Select All</button>
```

**JavaScript #1**

Get all the checkboxes using the name field,

```
document.getElementById('select').onclick = function() {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('vehicle');
    for (var checkbox of checkboxes) {
    checkbox.checked = false;
    }
}
```

**JavaScript #2**

If there is no other input tags other than checkboxes,

```
document.getElementById('select').onclick = function() {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var checkbox of checkboxes) {
    checkbox.checked = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
jQuery('my_selector_of_checkboxes').prop('checked', false).trigger()
```