# jQuery: Disable all checkboxes apart from current one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have checkboxes that need to act in a similar fashion to radio button controls.  Essentially when one is checked all others need to be unchecked.  How can I achieve this with as little pain as possible?

So to summarise.  If a checkbox is checked, all others (siblings) must then be unchecked leaving the clicked one checkstate untouched.

I already know how to uncheck all checkboxes but if I did this, I would have to first store the checked state of the checkbox that was checked, then reapply it after unchecking all checkboxes.  I wondered if there was a way of doing this with some fancy jQuery selectors or some such.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279760/how-to-reset-all-checkboxes-using-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: I know how to do that, I'm really looking for better way than storing the state of the original checkbox then reapplying it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**By using radio buttons.** Seriously, radio buttons are there for a reason. People expect radio buttons to be a "1 out of n" selection and checkboxes to be a "0 up to n" selection.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/AVEjt/

But please, only use it if you actually need to allow the user to uncheck everything. Then it's acceptable - otherwise radio buttons are much better.

Comment: I'm sure he's got a valid reason for using them. This is really a comment and not an answer.

Comment: - my -1 for actually helping in the end.

Comment: I've included the answer half a minute after posting the "comment". ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it is not appropriate to use them for my application

Comment: @Thief No need for `.not(this)`. The `this` element is not part of `$(this).siblings()`.

Comment: of course if your checkboxes aren't all within exact same parent element (e.g. if you have them layed out within a table) the `siblings()` method won't work

Comment: As a note, I've come across an actual reason for needing this. I have a range of checkboxes that need to allow N selected if a previous field is selected, or allow 1 if it is not. This is better than changing the input type visually, so sometimes this is warranted.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(':checkbox').not( selector_for_current ).attr('checked', false);
```

Where `selector_for_current` is the "current one", often `this` if you're in a callback.

Comment: Do I need to use `$(this)` or will just `this` suffice as it is within a jQuery function?

Comment: `this` is the DOM element (inside an event handler etc), `$(this)` a jQuery object. As a `.not()` argument a DOM element is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings("input[type=checkbox]:not(this)").attr("checked", "");
    });
});
```

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Drackir/3WrQR/).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to ThiefMaster's very good answer you could register the event on the parent form and catch all checkboxes, including those nested in a fieldset (or some other element) that would be missed using "siblings".

```
$("#myform").click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is("input:checkbox")) {
        $("input:checkbox", this).not(e.target).removeAttr("checked");
    }
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Gs3wa/