# Select All checkboxes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html code:

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="ckbCheckAll" />
    <p id="checkBoxes">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="Checkbox1" />
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="Checkbox2" />
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="Checkbox3" />
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="Checkbox4" />
        <br />
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" id="Checkbox5" />
        <br />
    </p>
```

When user checks `ckbCheckAll` all checkboxes must be checked. Also I have following jquery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ckbCheckAll").click(function () {
            $(".checkBoxClass").attr('checked', this.checked);
        });
    });
```

When I see my page in the browser I get the following result:
In the first click on `ckbCheckAll` all checkboxes were checked (which is correct). In the second click on `ckbCheckAll` all checkboxes were unchecked (which is correct). But in 3rd attempt nothing happened! also in 4th attempt nothing happened and so on.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select all checkboxes with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228382/select-all-checkboxes-with-jquery)

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Use prop

```
$(".checkBoxClass").prop('checked', true);
```

or to uncheck:

```
$(".checkBoxClass").prop('checked', false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sVQwA/

```
$("#ckbCheckAll").click(function () {
    $(".checkBoxClass").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Updated JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/sVQwA/1/

Comment: You're not checking to see if the .checkBoxClass is checked first.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, so what? they all need to be checked, it doesn't matter whether they were or not.

Comment: He is looking for the additional behaviors - check if not checked, uncheck if checked.

Comment: He worked on better code which does not require IF statement. I learned something.

Comment: I like your style @dmk. Really Impressed. +1.

Comment: FYI: updated fiddle to uncheck the check all box if you uncheck a child checkbox. http://jsfiddle.net/sVQwA/1/

Answer (score 8):

Use below code..

```
        $('#globalCheckbox').click(function(){
            if($(this).prop("checked")) {
                $(".checkBox").prop("checked", true);
            } else {
                $(".checkBox").prop("checked", false);
            }                
        });


        $('.checkBox').click(function(){
            if($(".checkBox").length == $(".checkBox:checked").length) { 
                 //if the length is same then untick 
                $("#globalCheckbox").prop("checked", false);
            }else {
                //vise versa
                $("#globalCheckbox").prop("checked", true);            
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is a simple way to do this :

Html :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="selectall" class="css-checkbox " name="selectall"/>Selectall<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxall" value="checkbox1"/>checkbox1<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxall" value="checkbox2"/>checkbox2<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxall" value="checkbox3"/>checkbox3<br>
```

jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#selectall").click(function(){
        if(this.checked){
            $('.checkboxall').each(function(){
                $(".checkboxall").prop('checked', true);
            })
        }else{
            $('.checkboxall').each(function(){
                $(".checkboxall").prop('checked', false);
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Updated the code so it will work for the latest jquery

Answer (score 3):

Try the following simple code:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() { this.checked = true; });
```

Source: [How to reset all checkboxes using jQuery or pure JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6035740/55075)

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
if (this.checked)
   $(".checkBoxClass").attr('checked', "checked");
else
   $(".checkBoxClass").removeAttr('checked');
```

also you can use `prop` please check http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: prop() should be used for this.

Comment: just added the prop but prop added the jquery in later versions for that reasons I don t prefer it but it s a personal choose of course...

Comment: @JayBlanchard how i can do this?

Comment: -1 because `prop` is the way to go and not just "some alternative".

Comment: prop() is not a personal choice. In newer versions of jQuery attr() should only be used for things with text-based values. prop() should be used for Booleans, objects, etc.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: Your explanation is pretty wrong. It's attributes (`x.setAttribute('foo', ..)`, `x.getAttribute('foo')`) vs properties (`x.foo`). `value` is something that's a string but should always be handled as a *property* for example.

Comment: @JayBlanchard thank you. I just replaced 'attr' with 'prop'. It works fine!

Comment: jQuery 1.6 (which introduces `prop()`) was released in may 2011. That's almost 2 years ago.

Comment: True @ThiefMaster, I just didn't type out the whole explanation

Answer (score 1):

I have seen many answers to this question and found some answer is lengthy and some answer is a little bit wrong. I have created my own code by using the above IDs and class.

```
$('#ckbCheckAll').click(function(){
        if($(this).prop("checked")) {
            $(".checkBoxClass").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $(".checkBoxClass").prop("checked", false);
        }                
    });


    $('.checkBoxClass').click(function(){
        if($(".checkBoxClass").length == $(".checkBoxClass:checked").length) { 
            $("#ckbCheckAll").prop("checked", true);
        }else {
            $("#ckbCheckAll").prop("checked", false);            
        }
    });
```

In the above code, where user clicks on select all checkbox and all checkbox will be selected and vice versa and second code will work when the user selects checkbox one by one then select all checkbox will be checked or unchecked according to a number of checkboxes checked.

Answer (score 0):

Use prop() instead -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ckbCheckAll").click(function () {
            $(".checkBoxClass").each(function(){
                if($(this).prop("checked", true)) {
                    $(this).prop("checked", false);
                } else {
                    $(this).prop("checked", true);
                }                
            });
        });
    });
```

BUT I like @dmk's much more compact answer and +1'd it

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ckbCheckAll').click(function() {
        $('.checkBoxClass').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('checked',!$(this).attr('checked'));
        });
    });
});
```

OR

```
$(function () {
    $('#ckbCheckAll').toggle(
        function() {
            $('.checkBoxClass').prop('checked', true);
        },
        function() {
            $('.checkBoxClass').prop('checked', false);
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ckbCheckAll").click(function () {
        $("#checkBoxes input").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
});
```

That should do it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#ckbCheckAll').click(function(event) { 
            if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $('.checkBoxClass').each(function(){
                    $(this).prop("checked",true);
                });
            }
            else{
                $('.checkBoxClass').each(function(){
                    $(this).prop("checked",false);
                });
            }   
    }); 
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thank you for your answer. Posting an answer that only contains is generally not as helpful as it could be. Consider explaining how this code solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".class").on('click', function () {
        $(".checkbox).prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.
Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.

Answer (score 0):

**Let i have the following checkboxes**

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="select All" id="chk_selall">Select ALL<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" id="chk_byk">bike<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" id="chk_car">car 
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" id="chk_bus">Bus<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="scooty" id="chk_scooty">scooty
```

**Here is the simple code to select all and diselect all when the selectall check box will click**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#chk_selall").on("click", function () {

                $("#chk_byk").prop("checked", true); 
                $("#chk_car").prop("checked", true); 
                $("#chk_bus").prop("checked", true); 
                $("#chk_scooty").prop("checked", true); 


            })

            $("#chk_selall").on("click", function () {

                if (!$(this).prop("checked"))
                {
                    $("#chk_byk").prop("checked", false);
                    $("#chk_car").prop("checked", false);
                    $("#chk_bus").prop("checked", false);
                    $("#chk_scooty").prop("checked", false);             

                }
            });


        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

checkall is the id of allcheck box and cb-child is the name of each checkboxes that will be checked and unchecked depend on checkall click event

```
$("#checkall").click(function () {
                        if(this.checked){
                            $("input[name='cb-child']").each(function (i, el) {
                                el.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
                                el.checked = true;
                                el.parentElement.className = "checked";

                            });
                        }else{
                            $("input[name='cb-child']").each(function (i, el) {
                                el.removeAttribute("checked");
                                el.parentElement.className = "";
                            });
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery( function($){
    // add multiple select / deselect functionality
    $("#contact_select_all").click(function () {

        if($("#contact_select_all").is(":checked")){
            $('.noborder').prop('checked',true);
        }else
            $('.noborder').prop('checked',false);
    });

    // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
    $(".noborder").click(function(){

    if($(".noborder").length == $(".noborder:checked").length) {
        $("#contact_select_all").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $("#contact_select_all").removeAttr("checked");
    }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late, but I'm posting this for the upcoming developers.

For select all checkbox we need to check three conditions,
1. on click select all checkbox every checkbox should get selected
2. if all selected then on click select all checkbox, every checkbox should get deselected
3. if we deselect or select any of the checkbox the select all checkbox also should change.

with these three things we'll get a good result.for this you can approach this link https://qawall.in/2020/05/30/select-all-or-deselect-all-checkbox-using-jquery/
I got my solution from here, they have provided solution with examples.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="select_all"/> Select all</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" value="1"/> Check 1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" value="2"/> Check 2</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" value="3"/> Check 3</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" value="4"/> Check 4</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" value="5"/> Check 5</td>
</tr>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#select_all').on('click',function(){
    if(this.checked){
        $('.check').each(function(){
            this.checked = true;
        });
    }else{
         $('.check').each(function(){
            this.checked = false;
        });
    }
});

$('.check').on('click',function(){
    if($('.check:checked').length == $('.check').length){
        $('#select_all').prop('checked',true);
    }else{
        $('#select_all').prop('checked',false);
    }
});
```

});

hope this will help anyone ...:)

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery-2.1.0.min.js file

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

Write the codes given below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {   
    $("#checkAll").change(function() {
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked'); // Get Checkbox state
        if (this.checked) //If true then checked all checkboxes
           $(".classofyourallcheckbox").prop('checked', true);
        else
           $(".classofyourallcheckbox").prop('checked', false); //or uncheck all textboxes 
    }); 
});
</script>
```