# How to to Check/Uncheck check-box using JavaScript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i can add `checked` property using following code

```
$('#specificCheckBox').prop('checked', true);
```

but how can remove this property using jquery or Javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [check / uncheck checkbox using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420534/check-uncheck-checkbox-using-jquery)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't remove it, but set it to false:

```
$('#specificCheckBox').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: on input element there no true or false only checked property is enough, that is confusion for me.

Comment: @SwapL Here you want to set the property, not the attribute but ya it's quite confusing, see e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr  You could still set the attribute instead but using prop for this kind of 'property' is the preferred method

Comment: @SomnathKharat that's true! But OP was asking to remove it which IMHO is quite different than usual similar questions and still doesn't explain why you have posted an answer too ;)

Comment: issue is not for posting ans its for upvote and the qus is not for u.its for those who upvoted

Answer (score 1):

IN javascript:

```
document.getElementById("specificCheckBox").checked = false;
```

In Jquery:

```
$('#specificCheckBox').prop('checked', false);//version 1.6+
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/txU4w/)

```
$('#btnCheck').click(function(){
    $('#check').attr('checked', true);
});

$('#btnUncheck').click(function(){
    $('#check').attr('checked', false);
});
```