# jQuery uncheck checkbox if disabled

Tags: jquery, checkbox

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" value="14292" name="chec_emp[]" class="chec_emp">
    </td>
    <td>Test User One</td>
    <td>Autobot</td>
    <td>Shadow</td>
    <td>50</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" value="14293" name="chec_emp[]" class="chec_emp">
    </td>
    <td>Test User One</td>
    <td>Autobot</td>
    <td>Billed</td>
    <td>50</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" value="14292" name="chec_emp[]" class="chec_emp">
    </td>
    <td>Test User Two</td>
    <td>Autobot</td>
    <td>Billed</td>
    <td>50</td>
</tr>
```

To disable checkbox with duplicate value, following code is used

```
$('.chec_emp').each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':enabled')) {
        $('.chec_emp[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').not(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

But the below PHP condition makes it checked, as it falls under the defined condition

```
$class= "checked='checked'" ;
<input type="checkbox" class="chec_emp" <?php echo $class ;?> name="chec_emp[]" value="<?php echo $res_row['USERID']?>" />
```

The disabled `checkbox` is still `checked`. How to `uncheck` the disabled checkbox ?

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/refckjxe/

Comment: Also working fine for me in a quick test fiddle.

Comment: @Pls see updated question. its the php condition working on page load, where it again checks the checkbox. So after the page is load, need to check if any checkbox is disabled and checked, make it unchecked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checkbox has the attribute checked. So you need to work with this (my guess is you want to uncheck the checkbox if it´s disabled?). See e.g. the post here:
[check / uncheck checkbox using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420534/check-uncheck-checkbox-using-jquery)

EDIT:
Something like

```
$('.chec_emp').each(function(){
if ($(this).is(':enabled')) {
    $('.chec_emp[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').not(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled').prop('checked', false);
}
});
```

Comment: Ben: Would be great if you could combine above snippet with yours

Comment: It also unchecks the checkbox which is enabled (checkboxwith same value)