# Check Box Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

In 'Leave Type' dropdown there are 3 fields casual leave, maternity leave.  1,2,3,4,5... these are the date fields , I have converted these fields into days.

I want to ensure that if 'Leave Type' selected index is 0 then I couldn't check the check box.

```
  function(LeaveTypeSelectedIndex,chk)
   {
      if(LeaveTypeSelectedIndex==0)
      {

         chk..checked = false;
      }
   }
```

I have tried but i'm not going to my destination.
how do i do that. And Thanks in Advance

Comment: Seems a rather complicated up for entering two dates  and why a person is not at work

Comment: If you mean you want to disable the checkboxes, you should look at the `disabled` property instead of the `checked` property. Setting `checked` to false will risk erasing your user's checked dates if they accidentally revert to the first (default) choice.

Answer (score 2):

I think the way you try to uncheck the checkbox is the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17420580/524913 .

Basically, this is what you need to do:

```
$(chk).attr('checked', false);
```

Comment: Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` for boolean attributes (aka properties).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but you give no conditions to your if statement... and also I think you need it to be a variable...

```
function($LeaveTypeSelectedIndex,$chk) {
    if($LeaveTypeSelectedIndex==0) {
         $chk.checked = false;
    }
}
```