# Marking checkboxes as unselected with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to retrieve ids from permissions with AJAX

```
$('#verPermisos').click(function() {                
    var role = $('#roles :selected').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "populate",
        data: { role : role },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var permisoArreglo = data;
            $.each(permisoArreglo, function(index, value) {
                $("input:checkbox[value=" + permisoArreglo[index] + "]").attr("checked", true);
            });
        }
    });
```

However I also need it to reset the checkboxes every time its clicked Ive tried

```
$(this).closest('form').find("input[type=checkbox]").attr('checked', false);
$('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false);
```

I dont have any problem unchecking boxes invidually but when I use

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false);
```

it no longers checks any boxes

However it hasn't worked.

Comment: Try `prop('checked', false)`. Failing that, make sure that the AJAX request is hitting the `success` handler, and that the DOM traversal you're using is actually finding the element you expect it to

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check / uncheck checkbox using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420534/check-uncheck-checkbox-using-jquery)

Comment: It worked changing both to .prop thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This should work

**Javascript**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/7657/)

Answer (score 0):

Either `.attr('checked', false)` or `.prop('checked', false)` should work (at least with the latest version of jQuery. If neither of those work, the problem might be something else, such as something re-resetting it after it's reset triggers, or you might have just had a simple typo or never got to the portion of code you were trying it in.

```js
$(() => {
  $('#withAttr').click(() => { $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', false); });
  $('#withProp').click(() => { $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false); });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input type="checkbox" checked> Checkbox</p>
<button id="withAttr">Clear with Attr</button>
<button id="withProp">Clear with Prop</button>
```