# jquery - refresh buttons after dinamically uncheck radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a table with a lot of radio buttons. There is a "clear all" button that deselects everything. I am using similar code to perform it:

```
<input type="radio" name="selections[1]" id="selections_1_3" value="">

<script>
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#selections_1_3').prop('checked', false);
});
</script>
```

It works fine, the only issue is that the next time I try to select a button that was deselected via this code, I have to click twice because somehow the button may still be with checked attribute and performs nothing with a single click.

I have tried mouseup(), keyup(), and refresh(); but nothing solves.

Comment: This might point you in the right direction. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420534/check-uncheck-checkbox-using-jquery

Comment: @user3262111 that's exactly what I'm doing...

Comment: @HenryDev the code is up there

Comment: the question is very simple and direct but it's everything there.. if you have a page with radio buttons that simple line unchecked everything, I just want the other line to "refresh" the button so I don't need to click twice on the next time I have to select it. I don't know what you would like to see more..

Comment: it's exactly the same thing I am currently doing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are using is working fine for me as shown in the below code snippet

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="selections[1]" id="selections_1_1" value="">
<input type="radio" name="selections[2]" id="selections_1_2" value="">
<input type="radio" name="selections[3]" id="selections_1_3" value="">
<input type="radio" name="selections[4]" id="selections_1_4" value="">
<input type="button" id="button">
<script>
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#selections_1_1').prop('checked', false);
  $('#selections_1_2').prop('checked', false);
  $('#selections_1_3').prop('checked', false);
  $('#selections_1_4').prop('checked', false);
});
</script>
```

Comment: that's correct! I'll have to analyse what's causing this incompatibility. btw thanks