# attr() or removeAttr() doesn't work anymore when in ajax success instructions

Tags: jquery, ajax

I try to achieve a simple coding, but for some reason I can't understand, attributes doesn't work anymore in ajax success function.

```
$('#modaleCalendarEvent #tbPrenomPatient, #modaleCalendarEvent 
    #tbNomPatient').change(function(){
    CheckNomEtPrenom();
});
```

....

```
function CheckNomEtPrenom(){
    var prenom = $('#modaleCalendarEvent #tbPrenomPatient').val();
    var nom = $('#modaleCalendarEvent #tbNomPatient').val();

    ......

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "actions/blahblah.php",
        data: params,                  
        dataType: "json",
        dataFilter: function(data, type){ 
            return data;
        },
        error: function(xhj, statut, thrown){
            alert('Erreur: '+xhj.responseText);
        },
        success: function(resultat){
            if(resultat.Valeur == -1 || resultat.Valeur == 1)
            {
                $('#modaleCalendarEvent #cbxModalePatients').val(resultat.PatientID);
                $('#modaleCalendarEvent #tbManuel').removeAttr('checked'); // HERE
                $('#modaleCalendarEvent #tbManuel').trigger('change');
                Notify("info", prenom + " " + nom + " already exists. Selection updated");
            }
            else // -2 existe pas en base
            {
                VerifieMetier();
            }

            HideLoaderPage();
        }
    });
}
```

Before I call ajax, I can (even by console) add or remove the attribute 'checked' on #tbManuel successfully.
But when I'm in my success ajax section, remove or add attribute doesn't work. Graphically it doesn't check or uncheck the checkbox. and no event raised.

I can trigger it manually, but still the checked atttribute is not set or deleted and I can't test it.

A timer with instruction laucnhed after some seconds doesn't work neither.
And I go in my if inside success instructions, my "resultat.Valeur" is correctly set. In debug in chrome I can see step by step.

Does someone has an explaination? and maybe a solution ?
It's a simple case but really weird. Like the ajax success instructions are in another context or something like that.

Thanks a lot

Comment: um, is it a checkbox? you should not be removing attributes... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420534/check-uncheck-checkbox-using-jquery

Comment: Assuming `#tbManuel` is a checkbox, don't use `removeAttr()`. Use `prop('checked', false)` instead. Also, make sure you've not duplicated any `id` attributes in your page

Comment: I will check all these points, And will use 'prop' instead of removeAttr.
I'll keep you informed.

Comment: Free link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rory McCrossan wrote, don't use attributes to check/unckeck as it will produce an unknown behaviour.

Please use `$('[selection]').prop('checked', false)` if you want to force the input to be unchecked, or `$('[selection]').click()` if you only want to toggle its state.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's working. 
Just by trigering click on the checkbox , it does the trick.

Thanks a lot all for help and fast answers !
I learn also to use prop() instead of removeattr() and attr()

Have a nice day !