# How do I uncheck the checkbox after modal dialog button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

Here's my problem:

Fiddle here:
https://www.bootply.com/jMryRDRZNT

I need to display a warning message when a user clicks a checkbox.
A modal dialog is then displayed where user can click 'I understand' and 'Cancel'
When 'Cancel' button is clicked I want to uncheck the checkbox.

I try to do it this way:

```
$('#btnModalCancel').click(function() {
    $('chkImm').attr('checked', false);
});
```

tried also 'prop' instead of attr - still not working. It appears that after the dialog is displayed something is preventing the checkbox from changing.
I placed console.log('test') inside the function - it is called, but the checkbox is not getting unchecked... See the fiddle in the link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector for `chkImm` is wrong, use `#chkImm`

**For jQuery 1.6+ :**

[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) is deprecated for properties; use the new [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) function instead as:

```
$('#myCheckbox').prop('checked', true); // Checks it
$('#myCheckbox').prop('checked', false); // Unchecks it
```

**For jQuery < 1.6:**

To check/uncheck a checkbox, use the attribute `checked` and alter that. With jQuery you can do:

```
$('#myCheckbox').attr('checked', true); // Checks it
$('#myCheckbox').attr('checked', false); // Unchecks it
```

**Reference:**  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17420580/1715121

```js
$('#chkImm').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("#myModal").modal({
      backdrop: 'static',
      eyboard: false
    });
  }
});

$('#btnModalCancel').click(function() {
  $('#chkImm').attr('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <form class="form">
    <input id="chkImm" type="checkbox"><label>Turn on</label>
  </form>
</div>


<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Предупреждение, вы уверены!</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                            </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Блаблабла</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="btnModalAgree" class="btn btn-warning">Я уверен, и хочу продолжить</button>
        <button type="button" id="btnModalCancel" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Correct selector for checkbox will be `$('#chkImm')`
2. Use `prop` to change `checked` state.

---

```
$('#chkImm').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: upvoting as it was the first correct answer as compared to @Eleazar below , approx 31 secs difference

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam :-)

Answer (score 0):

Updated your code: https://www.bootply.com/GuRVklMhIa#

Try doing: document.getElementById("chkImm").checked = false;

Answer (score 0):

I've use this one to Show the modal:

```
$('#myCheckbox').attr("checked", "checked");
```

but it' will not work if you're hiding the modal by this:

```
$('#myCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
```

So to show and hide properly, Both I'm using PROP method during Showing and Hiding.

```
$('#myCheckbox').prop('checked', false); //To Hide
$('#myCheckbox').prop('checked', false); //To Show
```